# How can I capture the current directory as an absolute pathname in a make variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to get the current directory during a GNUmake file run put into a make variable.

What is the syntax to do this?  Something like this?

```
DIR := $(PWD)
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Um, no, `$PWD` is sometimes defined in your environment and thus inherited by make, but oftentimes not. You need `$CURDIR`.

```
DIR := ${CURDIR}
```

Comment: Doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion Note: not POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html In particular, `PWD` does not get updated on recursive invocations of `make -C`.

Comment: For reference: ***this is Windows-friendly*** and works in cmd, git bash, powershell, conemu... Compared to `$$PWD` which did not work for me anywhere (Context: our makefile was doing `docker run -v $$PWD:/opt ...` and docker was complaining with a non-descriptive `Mount denied: The source path "C:/Users/.../somedir;C" doesn't exist and is not known to Docker`)

Comment: Note: this does not work for included makefiles. It will report the path of the top-level makefile instead.

Answer (score 8):

If you have one makefile including another in a different directory, `PWD` and `CURDIR` aren't updated for the child makefile.  If that second makefile needs to know where it is, the following will tell you.

```
$(dir $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```