# How to get the basename of the current folder as variable in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, directory

I want to copy a file to a server using `scp`. But I want to use my current folder name in my makefile as variable.

I know I get my current path using `$(CURDIR)` but my local path isn't the same on my remote server.

E.g. my path is `/Users/obstschale/Documents/Lab2/` and I want to copy Lab2.tar to `user@server.au:/home/path/Lab2/`.

```
copy2server:
    echo $(CURDIR)
    scp Lab2.tar user@server.au:/home/path/{folder}
```

I probably have to pipe `$(CURDIR)` into something and find my last folder.

Update: `$(CURDIR)` is the right variable. `$(CURID)` is the wrong one at least it didn't work for me.

Comment: full path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050231/how-can-i-capture-the-current-directory-as-an-absolute-pathname-in-a-make-variab

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I didn't have luck with the backtick syntax in makefiles (GNU Make 3.81) as Sylvain describes it. If it doesn't work for you either, use

```
$(shell basename $(CURDIR))
```

instead of

```
`basename $(CURDIR)`
```

Comment: this works for me :) But if I do `Folder=$(shell basename $(CURDIR)); echo $Folder` it will print 'older'. What's wrong?

Comment: $(Folder) instead of $Folder. ;-)

Comment: This is the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for included makefiles. It will report top-level makefile path instead.

Comment: Needed to wrap the `$(CURDIR)` in quotes to avoid issues from spaces: `$(shell basename "$(CURDIR)")`

Answer (score 11):

I tried this rule:

```
test:
    @echo $(CURDIR)           # e.g. /tmp/foobar/blafoor/baz
    @echo $(notdir $(CURDIR))  # gives "baz" here.
```

which worked fine for me.

maybe this is not intended to work, because `notdir` should

> Extract the non-directory part of each file name.

Comment: doesn't work for directories, only files. e.g. `$(notdir /home/user/dir/)` returns empty.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to strip the last folder name in the path out, there are a number of built in makefile functions.  See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_8.html#SEC74 for a quick overview of file operations.

```
copytoserver:
    scp Lab2.tar user@server.au:/home/path/$(notdir $(CURDIR))
```

The key item of this is of course `$(notdir $(CURDIR))`.  As you discovered, the `$(CURDIR)` contains the path to the directory in which the makefile was run, without the final '/'.  The `notdir` function strips off everything up to and including the last '/' in a filename.  This ends up stripping off everything but the final directory.

If `$(CURDIR)` still has the trailing '/', you can strip that off so the `notdir` function will do what you want like so:

```
$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(CURDIR)))
```

Note that spacing in this case is critically important, placing a space before or after any of the commas will insert a space when it does the greedy pattern substitution.

Comment: If you have the directory with trailing '/' in a variable like here, you could also shorten it to `$(notdir $(CURDIR:/=))` using [substitution references](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs)

Comment: Interesting, this does not seem to work with GNU Make 4.4.1 `echo $(basename $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))))` (to get path makefile is at)... it will show "/home/user/full/path" still. as if basename was not used.

Comment: @gcb did you debug the steps? Is there an added or missing `/`? The `patsubst` might not be matching what you think. The logic for these functions hasn't changed since they were introduced (in 1.0?), so maybe the way paths are stored in the `MAKEFILE_LIST` has and you'll need to debug. Try echoing each nested part to see where it breaks for you.

Comment: @mtalexan don't remember the details now. I think I recall that it works all the way until basename. I recall it worked fine if there was no tailing slash on the dirs, but abspath on MAKEFILE_LIST did always have the tailing slash. I gave up and didn't save notes. so i might be recalling wrong. i only recall the solution looked like to add yet another string substitution so I didn't think it was looking good  and went wit hardcoded paths :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `basename` shell command to extract the last component part of `$(CURDIR)`.

```
copyserver:
   folder=`basename "$(CURDIR)"`; scp Lab2.tar user@server.au:/home/path/${folder}
```

Comment: This needs a `$` in front of `{folder}`.

Comment: This solution is creating an inline shell variable using shell commands, then using the shell variable in the same line/subshell. If they need to use it elsewhere, they'd have to repeat the part at the start. However, they can shell out during variable value evaluation like `FILE=$(shell basename "$(CURDIR)")`

Answer (score -1):

As of GNU Make 4.3, you can use the native `notdir` Make function, like so:

```
some_file := /some/path/file.ext

notdir_result := $(notdir $(some_file))
basename_result := $(shell basename $(some_file))

$(info 'notdir' on $(some_file) produces: $(notdir_result))
$(info 'basename' command on $(some_file) produces: $(basename_result))
```

The above Makefile produces when run:

```
'notdir' on /some/path/file.ext produces: file.ext
'basename' command on /some/path/file.ext produces: file.ext
```

For more information about available functions, see the GNU Make info manual: `info "(make) File Name Functions"`.

Comment: `$(basename ...)` in GNU Make 4.3 does not produce the same result as `/usr/bin/basename`. The Make `basename` removes suffixes. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-basename-1

Comment: Good point.  I guess my answer still has some value in other contexts where only directory names without extensions are involved.

Comment: From the GNU Make doc:
> For example,
`$(basename src/foo.c src-1.0/bar hacks)`
produces the result `‘src/foo src-1.0/bar hacks’`.  So it really does something quite different: it removes a suffix (like `/usr/bin/basename -s` _and_ it does not strip the directory part.

Comment: Ah! it's `notdir` I should have used.  Will update the answer.